# Cannot access woocommerce rest api in wordpress 5.8.1

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I run woocommerce from [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress) `5.8.1-apache` with `mysql 5.7` (via docker-compose)

After I have Generated API keys in woocommerce  as stated in the guidelines, I try to access the url http://localhost:8180/wp-json/wc/v3/products (I expose 80 to 8180 on host) but I get a page saying:

> Not Found The requested URL was not found on this server.
>
> Apache/2.4.51 (Debian) Server at localhost Port 8180

The [same guidelines](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/) also say that I have to enable permalinks:

> WordPress permalinks must be enabled at: Settings > Permalinks.

But when I go to `Settings->Permalinks` section I don't see any checkbox or option saying "enable permalinks".

What am I missing?

Comment: There is no "enable permalinks" option. I guess that what the guide wants you to do is to go to Settings > Permalinks, pick any of the permalink options (except for Plain), then click on Save to apply changes.

Comment: @cabrerahector That was it! Thank you. Please add it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in order to actually be able to use the WC REST API -as the guide says- you need to make sure that you're using "pretty permalinks" (a.k.a. not the "Plain one").

Go to **Settings > Permalinks**, then pick any of the permalink options (eg. *Post name*), then save changes.